# Web-based Reporting Tools (similar to Tableau)

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, report, business-intelligence

I am looking for a reporting tool for my end users to build their own reports using their data which is stored in a MySQL DB.  I have researched this on stackoverflow and most of the solutions seem to be desktop apps or web-based services which allow you to upload data which is not an options.

I would prefer this software to be a Flash-based solution or just HTML (I guess Java is fine as well), it would act at **Tableau** does; which is provide a dashboard / wizard which allows you to mash up your data with maps, plot the data on various charts and possibly save the chart as well.

Anything like this exist? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't put much stock in the report itself, [Gartner's Magic Quadrant report](http://www.gartner.com/technology/media-products/reprints/tableau/article1/article1.html) at least lists several possibilities for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out our product named [ActiveAnalysis](http://ActiveAnalysis.grapecity.com) (previously named Data Dynamics Analysis). It allows your end users to perform interactive, drag & drop analysis on the web against a relational database or an optimized OLAP database (e.g. Analysis Services). However, since it is a programmable component a .NET developer can customize and integrate it into your applications.

See http://ActiveAnalysis.grapecity.com for more information.

Comment: The new site for ActiveAnalysis is here: http://activeanalysis.grapecity.com